# Fatal error while unwrapping optional value in swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting the following error when i try to update a label in swift.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

There must be something I am missing. These are the two variables involved:

[Label and Double variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKoCg.jpg)

And this is the `func` where I seem to get the error:

[Method to update label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thzgG.png)

As far as I can see the variable that I want to update the label with has a value of `19.875531899929` and I want the label to show the `Int` part of that. Where does the nil come from? I am stuck finding the bug.

Can the fact that I called the method from a ViewController instance in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of **AppDelegate.swift** have anything to do with it? This is the short code to call the method:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {         

    viewControllerInstance.convertAlertTimeToCountdownFromMinutes() 

}
```

And the variable in **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
var viewControllerInstance = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UILabel` object is nil, you forgot to connect your `IBOutlet` with your `viewController`'s Label, try to connect the `IBOutlet` with `UILabel`s named **lblMinutes** and **lblMinutesTag**.

**New Edit**

If you want to update the value of label when your app become active you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for that, add below code inside your `viewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationBecameActive:",
           name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,object: nil)
}

func applicationBecameActive(notification: NSNotification){
    self.convertAlertTimeToCountdownFromMinutes() 
}

deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I have Ctrl-dragged both labels to **ViewController.swift**. Can the fact that I called the method from a ViewController instance in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of **AppDelegate.swift** have anything to do with it?

Comment: You are calling this `updateLblMinutes()` method from **AppDelegate.swift**? Can you show the code that you have written inside `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.

Comment: Certainly. It's not much but:

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  
      viewControllerInstance.convertAlertTimeToCountdownFromMinutes()

        }

Comment: Hmm ... that lost all its formatting during save and I can't find how to add images in comments.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question. i'm not sure if I'm supposed to write that or if you get some kind of update automatically.

Comment: How should it be declared to not produce nil in the label?

Comment: Check my edit, Also remove the code that you have written inside `AppDelegate` methods.

Comment: It works. :-) Thank you very much for all your help!